# Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined in the Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create simple navigation in my ionic application, but I get following error.
Argument 'LoginCtrl' is not a function, got undefined in the Ionic
What I did wrong?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!— IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    —>

    <!— ionic/angularjs js —>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-cookies.js"></script>


    <script src="lib/ng-cordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <!— cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) —>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!— your app's js —>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/restService/login.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
          <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic',
    'Authentication',
    'ngCookies'])

  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
   //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('views/main')

    $stateProvider.state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/throbber.html'
    })
  })

  .run(['$ionicPlatform', '$rootScope', '$location', '$cookieStore', '$http',
    function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $location, $cookieStore, $http) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      try {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
         cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);
      }
    });
  }]);
  angular.module('Authentication', []);
```

js/restService/login.js:

```
angular.module('Authentication')
.controller('LoginCtrl' [
  function () {
    alert('test');
  }
  ]);
```

views/throbber.html:

```
<div>THROBBER</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your login.js is loaded after app.js.
When you are configuring routes, LoginCtrl controller is not available to angular, therefore it is "undefined"/"not a function".

You need to have the contents of login.js moved into app.js, or have your gulp/grunt task runner to combine the contents.

Comment: It didn't help. I tried to copy login.js to app.js, I tried to create Authentication module before starter module, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @nuclearkote it is correct to place Authentication block before starter block. Have you tried clearing your browser cache or running in incognito mode?